# Why do i need to install bootstrap.css with ngx-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am starting a new Angular 4 project. I want to use ui-bootstrap; which is now ngx-bootstrap: http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/

In the past I only had to download ui-bootstrap as it included all core Bootstrap 3 styling plus the component re-writes, In the instructions on: http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/

it says:
You will need bootstrap styles (Bootstrap 3)

Why do I need to include/link Twitter Boostrap in addition to ngx-bootstrap unlike in the past?

Comment: I believe it is because it supports both bootstrap 3 and bootstrap 4. So you must install the desired bootstrap manually. And ngx-bootstrap does not install the dependency by its own.

Answer (score 2):

You can install with Angular CLI

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap bootstrap --save
```

then update `.angular-cli.json`

```
"styles": [
     "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css",
  ],
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Programmer detected

Answer (score 0):

In `ui-bootstrap` also `bootstrap.css` were necessary.

Find this link and check `Dependency` section - [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

**Dependencies**

**This repository contains a set of native AngularJS directives based on Bootstrap's markup and CSS**. As a result no dependency on jQuery or Bootstrap's JavaScript is required.

> The only required dependencies are:
>
> - AngularJS
> - Angular-animate
> - Angular-touch
> - **Bootstrap CSS**